# I have a problem with using the 'change' event. What can I do? What event I can use?

Tags: javascript

When I put some word by machine in the input box I want to call the test() function. With the 'change' event I need to click outside the input box to execute the 'change' event.

What can I do? What event I can use?

```
const scannerInput = document.querySelector('.scanner-input');
const check = document.querySelector(".check");
 
scannerInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    test();
    scannerInput.value = "";
    scannerInput.focus();
}); 

function test(params) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = `<td>${scannerInput.value}</td>`;
    check.append(tr);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you’re looking for the `input` event, but remember that just because it fires on every new character when you’re typing normally, it doesn’t mean that every input event represents one character. (See: IME, copy/paste, and more)

Comment: Use `input` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event instead of `change`